# C makefile errors

Tags: c, makefile

I have a custom header file example.h which has prototypes for a few functions. There is a .C file example.c that I implemented which "includes" (#include "example.h") and has the implementations of the functions that has prototype in example.h.  Now, I have another function test.c that calls the functions that are prototyped in example.h and defined in example.c.

My make file is as follows

```
test: test.o
    gcc -o test -g test.o

test.o: test.c example.c example.h  
    gcc -g -c -Wall test.c
    gcc -g -c -Wall example.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o test
```

I get following message for the functions that are defined in example.c

Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file

function1                        test.o

function2                        test.o

function3                        test.o

function4                        test.o

ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to test

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

*** Error code 1

make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test'

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: why aren't you linking example? you compiled it...

Answer (score 2):

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -g -o $@ $^

test: test.o example.o
    gcc -o -g $@ $^
```

`%.o: %.c` This means any `*.o` file should be builded from its equivalen from `c` files.

example `test.o` should be builded from `test.c` and `example.o` should be builded from `example.c`

Comment: The OP does not seem to be used to makefile rules and patterns, you should explain a little more. To clarify your answer you should : 1. Define what are $(CC), $(CFLAGS) and $(LDFLAGS) (give a little example with basic options), and 2. explain what are $@ and $^

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must include the example.o file when generating the executable file : `gcc -o test example.o test.o`. Then, the dependencies you wrote for target test.o are incorrect. You should split it like this :

```
test: test.o example.o
    gcc -o test test.o example.o
test.o: test.c
    gcc -c -Wall test.c
example.o: example.c
    gcc -c -Wall example.c
```

Then, consider the use of variables to store the names of your object files, the flags you want to pass to the linker/compiler etc... This would make your life much easier.

Comment: using the same rule for `test.o: test.c` and `example.o: example.c` is too much. you can reduce that in one rule. Use `%.o: %.c` instead and for the build command use `gcc -c -Wall -g -o $@ $^`

Comment: BTW the OP is using the -g as option in his gcc comands. you have to added it in your gcc command

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to give the OP a basic example without any use of special makefile rules (like `.c.o:` for instance). Clarify your answer for him and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Thank you, Retiro. That worked. 

i'm getting warning such as :

- implicit declaration of function XXXX
and a few more. How do you fix it?

PS: As much as I'd like to,being a newbie here, I cant upvote your answer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The "implicit declaration of function" means that at the time you call the function, it is not defined. Check whether you include all the header files you need or whether some declarations are missing (do not misunderstand : the declaration of a function is slightly different from the definition of a function).
And for more convenient makefile use, you should look Mohamed's answer

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation.  I fixed all the warnings except for these 2.

- I'm unable to fix implicit declaratoin warning for isdigit() function.

- Although I've have given a new line at the end of the last line, it says mksh: Warning: newline is not last character in file Makefile.

Comment: A quick `man isdigit` will show you that this function can be found under the 'ctype.h' standard header. You might be missing a `#include <ctype.h>` directive somewhere. For the second, it seems like make would like you to put new line characters at the end of your makefile (not the source files)

Comment: Oops, made a mistake in my previous comment, it is "...at the time you call the function, it is not declared", not "defined".

Answer (score 0):

`test.o: test.c example.c example.h

    gcc -g -c -Wall test.c
    gcc -g -c -Wall example.c`

as per your code test.o target is calling test.c example.c example.h target which i am not able to see.